# Indexing Postgresql JSONB arrays for element existence and unicity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, unique-constraint

I have a Postgresql 11.8 table named `posts` where I would like to define a column `slugs` of type JSONB, which would contain arrays of strings such as `["my-first-post", "another-slug-for-my-first-post"]`.

I can find a post having a specific slug using the `?` existence operator: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slugs ? 'some-slug'`.

Each post is expected to only have a handful of slugs but the amount of posts is expected to grow.

Considering the above query where `some-slug` could be any string:

- How can I define an index to have a reasonably performant query (no full table scan)?
- How can I ensure the same slug cannot appear multiple times (across and within the different arrays)?

I am primarily looking for a solution for Postgresql 11 but also would be interested to know solutions in future versions, if any.

The database is used in a Rails 6.0 app so I am also interested by the Rails migration syntax.

Comment: If you want to ensure uniqueness why not just use a table instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can support the `?` operator with a normal GIN index on the `jsonb` column.

However, you cannot enforce uniqueness of array values.

Particularly if you want to have database constraints, you should **not** model your data using JSON. Use a regular normalized data model with several tables and foreign keys, then it will be easy to implement such an uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. My challenge comes from additionally needing those slugs to be translated. I would like to avoid two levels of associations. I followed up with this question regarding Rails' Mobility translation library: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63841953/4623987